# Ĉu ekzistas pentristoj en esperantujo?

Tags: culture, literature

Estas verkistoj, sed mi ne povas trovi iajn pentristojn. Ĉu eĉ tiaj ekzistas?

Comment: Ĉu vi volas demandi specife pri pentristoj? Ĉar laŭ mia kompreno oni nomus ankaŭ verkiston artisto. Aŭ eble vi volas kritike diri ke la esperantaj verkistoj ne sukcesas krei belarton, ĉu?

Comment: Jes, specife pentristoj. Mi jhus shanghas la demandon, tre dankon.

Answer (score 6):

La pentristo Otto Dix uzis Esperanton por skribi poŝtkartojn dum la unua mondmilito:

> Otto Dix, likewise, sent hundreds of illustrated field postcards to Helene Jakob, the Dresden telephone operator he referred to as his “like-minded companion,” between June 1915 and September 1918. These sketches convey details both minute and panoramic, from the crowded trenches to the ruined fields and landmarks of France and Belgium. Often, their flip sides contain short greetings or cryptic lines of poetry written in both German and Esperanto.

Rigardu: http://blog.oup.com/2014/08/german-feldpostkarten-first-world-war/

Answer (score 4):

Nu se ili ekzistus, estus malfacile scii ĉar pentraĵoj malofte enhavas vortojn. Tamen, mi kredas ke pentristoj ja estas inter ni.

Comment: Sed chu iuj ajn kreas arton pri Eo? Ree, mi certas jes, sed mi ne povas trovi la arton